# Indexing within numpy array slow for high index values

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to write a function to compute the cross correlation of a signal, `in_`, with the result placed in `buffer`. However, I can't understand why this implementation:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('test')


@nb.njit
@cc.export('diff', '(f4[:], i8, f4[:], i8)')
def diff(in_, in_i, buffer, half_buffer_size):
    end_i = in_i+half_buffer_size
    for tau in range(half_buffer_size):
        temp = np.float32(0.0)
        for i in range(in_i, end_i):
            delta = in_[i] - in_[i + tau]
            temp += delta*delta
        buffer[tau] = temp
```

takes twice as long as this implementation:

```
@nb.njit
@cc.export('diff', '(f4[:], i8, f4[:], i8)')
def diff(in_, in_i, buffer, half_buffer_size):
    a = in_[in_i:2*half_buffer_size+in_i]
    for tau in range(half_buffer_size):
        temp = np.float32(0.0)
        for i in range(half_buffer_size):
            delta = a[i] - a[i + tau]
            temp += delta*delta
        buffer[tau] = temp
```

I even tried this but it is even slower than the two above:

```
@nb.njit
@cc.export('diff', '(f4[:], i8, f4[:], i8)')
def diff(in_, in_i, buffer, half_buffer_size):
    end_i = in_i+half_buffer_size
    i_list = list(range(in_i, end_i))
    for tau in range(half_buffer_size):
        temp = np.float32(0.0)
        for i in i_list:
            delta = in_[i] - in_[i + tau]
            temp += delta*delta
        buffer[tau] = temp
```

I am calling this code using the following:

```
@cc.export('test', '(f4[:], f4[:], i8, i8)')
def test(in_, buffer, half_buffer_size, num_of_iterations):
    for i in range(num_of_iterations):
        diff(in_, i, buffer, half_buffer_size)


in_ = np.zeros(shape=100000, dtype=np.float32)
buffer = np.zeros(shape=300, dtype=np.float32)

test.test(a1, a2, 150, 16000) # simulate one second of input samples
```

So I am getting 0.65 seconds for the first implementation, 0.35 for the second and 0.8 for the third. Why is the second implementation so much faster? This diff function represents the first step in the YIN pitch tracking algorithm: http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf

Comment: Curiously, if you replace `for i in range(in_i, end_i):` with `i = in_i; while i < end_i: pass` (and add `i += 1` at the end of the inner loop) the difference in the timings is reduced. Btw, you may consider passing `parallel=True` to `@nb.njit` and do `for tau in nb.prange(half_buffer_size):` to parallelize the iterations.

Comment: Are this the timings for the njit version or the exported version (I only get a few percent using njit with your version 1 and 2)? For clarifying the issue it would make sense to implement a optimized version too. (fastmath=True -> to make SIMD-vectorization of the reduction in principle possible and contiguous arrays. (This should run in less than 0.1s)

Comment: @max9111 Both have the issue. I presume because the length of in_ is not defined then some sort of bound checking is taking place in the slower implementation. The faster version uses array 'a' instead, the length of which is explicit within the function.